# How can I copy t2.col2 to t1.col3 where t1.col1 = t2.col1 in mysql?

Tags: mysql

t1 and t2 are tables. t1 has 3 columns, t2 has 2 columns. They have identical data in col1. Currently t1.col3 is empty. How can I fill it with appropriate data from t2?

Result of this query:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING (col1);
```

is exactly what I want t1 to be.

Comment: Can you show your desired result based on some sample input?

Answer (score 1):

you can use an insert select to achieve this.

```
insert into t1 (col3) 
select t2.col2 from t2, t1 where t2.col1 = t2.col1
```

Comment: clean up the aliases a bit (or whatever you are meaning to say in the where clause) ... and you aren't even doing a join

Comment: @Drew, updated the aliases, you don't necessarily need a join here

Comment: You just did a join. But you did it with circa 1995 non-explicit join style that no one uses anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can set up a view if you dont want to store duplicate values across tables. Simply

```
create view view_name as
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, t2.col2 FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 USING (col1);
```